# VBA Selenium - Find Button to Click in Container that has multiple very similar entries

Tags: vba, select, button, selenium-chromedriver, path-finding

Apologies Newbie so hope posting in correct format

I am trying to find and click a button.
This is for a tee booking sheet where there is a seperate button (Text = Book) for each time available.
I need to get to the Div Class 'controls' section and find within that a time (say 07:54) and if found click.

I have tried

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("*//div[@class,'Controls' contains(text(),'07:54')]").Click

obj.FindElementByPartialLinkText("07:54").Click
```

and various others which do not work and

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("//*//*[@id='booking-teesheet-container']/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/a").Click
```

which works but does not enable me to search for a specific time
As you can see I am not well versed in VBA Selenium.

Any assistance appreciated

```html
<div class="tee available" data-hour-val="9" data-min-val="22" data-teetime="2021-03-30 09:22">
    <div class="time theme_bg">
        09:22
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" data-players-view-ctr="09:22">
            <div class="player player-free view" data-players-view="09:22"><span>P</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i> View Players</div>
        </div>
        <div class="players col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6" data-players="09:22">
            <div class="player player-free">
                <span>P1</span>

                <a data-teetime-selected="2021-03-30 09:22" href="/Members/BookingAdd?dateTime=2021-03-30T09%3A22&amp;courseId=7738&amp;startPoint=1&amp;crossOverStartPoint=0&amp;crossOverMinutes=0">
                    Available
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="player player-free">
                <span>P2</span>

                <a data-teetime-selected="2021-03-30 09:22" href="/Members/BookingAdd?dateTime=2021-03-30T09%3A22&amp;courseId=7738&amp;startPoint=1&amp;crossOverStartPoint=0&amp;crossOverMinutes=0">
                    Available
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="player player-free">
                <span>P3</span>

                <a data-teetime-selected="2021-03-30 09:22" href="/Members/BookingAdd?dateTime=2021-03-30T09%3A22&amp;courseId=7738&amp;startPoint=1&amp;crossOverStartPoint=0&amp;crossOverMinutes=0">
                    Available
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="player player-free">
                <span>P4</span>

                <a data-teetime-selected="2021-03-30 09:22" href="/Members/BookingAdd?dateTime=2021-03-30T09%3A22&amp;courseId=7738&amp;startPoint=1&amp;crossOverStartPoint=0&amp;crossOverMinutes=0">
                    Available
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="controls">
                <a
                    data-book="1"
                    data-teetime-selected="2021-03-30 09:22"
                    href="/Members/BookingAdd?dateTime=2021-03-30T09%3A22&amp;courseId=7738&amp;startPoint=1&amp;crossOverStartPoint=0&amp;crossOverMinutes=0"
                    class="btn btn-primary theme_bg theme_border_primary"
                >
                    Book
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Richard, did any of the answers helped in any way? We posted answers to your question and have received zero feedback from you. Good or bad, some feedback is better than none at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attribute= value selectors. Say you want to book a time (irrespective of date), you can use

```
FindElementByCss(".controls [data-teetime-selected*='09:22']").click
```

This looks for `data-teetime-selected` attribute with value 09:22 in.

If you want to specify date:

```
[data-teetime-selected*='2021-03-30 09:22']
```

To select for the player free links e.g.

```
[data-players='09:22'] .player-free
```

What I can't tell from the html is whether this attribute `data-teetime-selected` is dynamically added after performing some other step.

Comment: Thank youNot sure how to mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with Selenium per se. Your problem is understanding how XPath (or other locator strategies) work. Your problem, as I see it, is that you are trying to discriminate against multiple web elements that are almost identical.

```
<a data-teetime-selected="2021-03-30 09:22" ...>...</a>
```

The question is, how can you tell them apart? You got to find distinguishable attributes or values to tell them apart. One way is by link text. You have 4 attributes that have a text value of "Available". If you needed to get one of those, it would have been very hard because all four are completely identical. You would have to resort to simply select the first of the four. For that, you can use `findElementByXPath` and that will return the first element that matches the expression. Alternatively, you could use `findElementsByXPath` and that returns a list you could iterate through.

Fortunately, this is not the case here. For the other element, you could use an XPath expression like this one: `//a[contains(@data-teetime-selected, '09:22') and contains(text(), 'Book')]`.

[image]

---

### Other suggestions

1. Avoid using `//*` - Attempting to find "any" element meeting certain criteria can result in false matches. Be more specific (notice I used `//a` for my expression)
2. Avoid using indexing in your expressions - `../div/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/a` an expression like this is extremely unpredictable and susceptible to changes in the structure of the page; thus resulting in matching wrong elements. Also, such long expression brings up my next point...
3. Get as close to the needed element as possible - Not always, but often it is better to do something like `//div/a` than `../div/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/a`. And in the cases when this is not true, you could use attributes and values of those elements to refine your path (i.e. `//div[@id='foo']//div/a`)
4. Learn to use [XPath axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) effectively.